# swift - pythonKit crashes on release version

Tags: python, swift, xcode, release, swift-pythonkit

I'm trying to use pythonKit in order to run a Pyhton code from swift.

This code works fine:

```
let sys = Python.import("sys")
      sys.path.append("Users/fusic/Desktop/PyrhonTest/PyrhonTest/")
      let example = Python.import("main")
    button.title = String(example.hello()) ?? ""
```

Then, I archive my project and run the app's release version. When pythonKit is called, the app crashes.
These is the beginning of the report log. Any ideas how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue... any success?

Comment: @amit-hagin Any success with this? I am also facing same problem. Working fine in debug mode and fails in release mode

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to turn off `Enable Bitcode` and set `Strip Style` to `Debugging Symbols` for both Release and Debug.

Comment: Thats still giving crash to me

Comment: The last, setting Strip Style to Debugging Symbols did the trick for me! You are a literal genius. Tysm!